# If $S_{n,m}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^m =\sum_{j=0}^{m-1} A_{n,j}(m) S_{n,j},$ what are $A_{n,j}(m)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, summation-method

We know the sum of first $n$ natural numbers, their squares and cubes. sum of higher powers can be worked out using the differences: $k^m-(k-1)^{m}$. However, these formulas are not remembered well. Recently, Dr. Mythili Subramanian and I  have started wondering if one can write
$$S_{n,m}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^m =\sum_{j=0}^{m-1} A_{n,j}(m)~ S_{n,j} $$ then what are the expression/name for the coefficients: $A_{n,j}(m)?$

Interestingly, we know the asymptotic result that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^m \sim \frac{n^{m+1}}{m+1}, ~\text{when $n$ is large}.$$
Any suggestion, information or help is welcome here. We are also trying to get it.

Comment: +1 : Very interesting question, that I've never seen posed before.

Comment: @Gary, yes  you are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the $A_{n,j}$ are allowed to depend on $m$ as well, one can proceed as follows. We start with
$$
k^m  = \sum\limits_{j = 0}^{m - 1} {( - 1)^{m + j - 1} \binom{m}{j}S_{k,j} } .
$$
Summing over $k$ gives
\begin{align*}
S_{n,m} & = \sum\limits_{j = 0}^{m - 1} {( - 1)^{m + j - 1} \binom{m}{j}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {S_{k,j} } } 
\\ & = \sum\limits_{j = 0}^{m - 1} {( - 1)^{m + j - 1} \binom{m}{j}(n + 1)S_{n,j} }  - \sum\limits_{j = 0}^{m - 1} {( - 1)^{m + j - 1} \binom{m}{j} S_{n,j + 1} } 
\\ & =  - mS_{n,m}  + ( - 1)^{m - 1} n(n + 1) + \sum\limits_{j = 1}^{m - 1} {( - 1)^{m + j - 1} \left[ \binom{m}{j}(n + 1) + \binom{m}{j-1} \right]S_{n,j} } .
\end{align*}
Thus,
$$
S_{n,m}  = \sum\limits_{j = 0}^{m - 1} {( - 1)^{m + j - 1} \frac{1}{{m + 1}}\left[ \binom{m}{j}(n + 1) + \binom{m}{j-1} \right]S_{n,j} } .
$$

Comment: Excellent work  and improvisation Gary!